# What does below line mean in POM?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have below line in POM:

```
<outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Did you try searching the same ?

Comment: Pretty much what it says, I think - that's the root class-path for the built src/main code - i.e. it will contain resources you copy over with the build and the first directory in your namespace.

Comment: You should add the surrounding XML elements, since a outDirectory may occur on several places (depending on used plugins) in a POM.

Answer (score 0):

Its the build directory where classes are built.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this line inside a configuration of some plugin. Assuming its a maven war plugin, its a path where your WAR will be stored.
You can read about war plug-in 
[here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks for your reply. yes it is plugin. maven-compiler-plugin. what does this do?

Comment: It should build your WAR (web archive). You should have a line <packaging>war</packaging> in your pom.xml somewhere, it would mean, that the module is designed to be a war, and thats what maven builds... It has various configurations, and you've faced one of them. You should really take a look on the link I've sent you, there you'll find an information about everything it supports.

Comment: <build>
  <finalName>WebAstras</finalName>
  <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <verbose>true</verbose>
     <executable>${JAVA_HOME}\bin\java.exe</executable>
     <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin></plugins></build>...i have this config.